# Create flat list from tree ordered by the tree order

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, tree

I'm working on C# and i'm looking for a simple way to take a list that represent a tree and flat the tree to a list with the same order as in the tree.

I have 4 properties per node:
* ID
* ParentID,
* Seq
* Name

```
public class MyNode  
{  
   public int ID{get;set;}  
   public int ParentID{get;set;}  
   public int SeqID{get;set;}  
   public string Name{get;set;}  
}
```

And i have a collection of MyNode:

```
List<MyNode> FlatListOfNodes{get;set;}
```

I'm looking for something that will look like this:
`FlatListOfNodes.OrderBy(something).DoAnotherThing1(somthing)...`.

that will order the list in the same order that is in the tree.

for example if will have this tree:

```
-- Parent1
     -- Child 1.1  
     -- Child 1.2  
        -- grandson 1.2.1  
        -- grandson 1.2.2  
        -- grandson 1.2.3
    -- Child 1.3
-- Parent2
     -- Child 2.1  
     -- Child 2.2  
        -- grandson 2.2.1  
        -- grandson 2.2.2  
        -- grandson 2.2.3
    -- Child 2.3
        -- grandson 2.3.1
        -- grandson 2.3.2
```

I want to represent it in a flat list by the same order.

in this example:

- Parent1 have ID=32, ParentID=-1,SeqID=1,Name="Parent1"
- Child1.2 have ID=412, ParentID=32,SeqID=2, Name="Child1.2"
- Grandson 1.2.1 have ID=231, ParentID=412, SeqID=1, Name="grandson 1.2.1"
- Parent2 will have ID=345,ParentID=-1,SeqID=2,Name="Parent2"
- Child2.3 with have ID=785, ParentID=345, SeqID=3, Name="Child 2.3"
- Grandson 2.3.1 will have ID=854, ParentID=785, SeqID=1, Name= "grandson 2.3.1"

**What is the best way to do it?

Is there some way to do it with linq?**

Thanks!

Comment: You can go through the list recersively

Comment: I guess you should have a look at [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: SelectMany can't be used in this case. It's not a collection inside a collection

Comment: I think you're looking for *pre-order traversal* for which there are plenty of references online. (And `SelectMany` can be used, but it is harder than a more direct recursive iterator: this is something that is easier without LINQ.)

Comment: Is it possible to add another string property to MyNode, which can be set to the overall sequence(1.2, 2.3.1 etc.). This can be done by concatenating current node's sequence to that of the parent. Sorting by this property should give the order you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your tree can be generalized as an [m-ary tree](http://pioneer.netserv.chula.ac.th/~skrung/2301232/Lecture011.html). Given that, your flat list can be calculated by performing a depth first traversal (DFT) of that tree. I suspect that will be fastest as LINQ does not assume your data structure has any definite structure. [Here's a quick article on DFT for binary search trees](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/breadth-first-and-depth-first-traversal-of-a-c-binary-search-tree/) - DFT for m-ary trees is an abstraction on that concept.

<strike>There seems to be no natural ordering of any of your state variables. You'll have to come up with some ways of breaking ties between children (e.g. why is Parent1 visited before Parent2 - some comparator told the algorithm to visit Parent1 first). The comparison could be based on something as simple as order of generation (e.g. oldest child first).</strike> As is mentioned in a comment below, compare on SeqID to select the next focus node to recurse on.

Comment: They can be ordered by SeqID. First by the parent's SeqID, then by their own.

Comment: The parent parent does not have ID so it will be -1 for example. in this case all the roots node will be sorted one after another. After all the root each of the child will be places and not under their parents(each one under it's own parent). Also this will be at the first level, in the second and third level it will not work and also the order is not by the ID so if you say that "then by their own" it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new. I knew there was `sary`, but didn't know about `m-ary`! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two passes. First, you create a dictionary of nodes, each of which has a list of children.

```
class TreeNode
{
    public MyNode NodeData;
    public List<MyNode> Children = new List<MyNode>();
}
```

For example:

```
Dictionary<int, MyNode> nodesDict = new Dictionary<int, MyNode>();
// add the parent node
nodesDict.Add(-1, new TreeNode{NodeData = new MyNode{ID=1, ParentID=0, SeqID=1, Name="Root"}});

// now go through the original list of nodes
foreach (var node in NodesList)
{
    // If there is an entry for this node already in the dictionary,
    // then update its NodeData.
    // Otherwise create a new entry.
    TreeNode dictNode;
    if (nodesDict.TryGetValue(node.ID, out dictNode))
    {
        dictNode.NodeData = node;
    }
    else
    {
        // add this node to the dictionary
        dictNode = new TreeNode{NodeData = node};           
        nodesDict.Add(node.ID, dictNode);
    }

    // find this node's parent, and add the node to the child list
    // if the node's parent doesn't exist, add it
    TreeNode parentNode;
    if (!nodesDict.TryGetValue(node.ParentID, out parentNode))
    {
        // Parent doesn't yet exist.
        // Create an entry for it.
        parentNode = new TreeNode();
        nodesDict.Add(node.ParentID, parentNode);
    }
    // Add this node to the parent's children
    parentNode.Children.Add(node);
}
```

Now what you have is a dictionary that contains an entry for each tree node, and the tree nodes know what their children are. At this point, all you care about is the node with ID -1. All of the other nodes can be reached from there.

```
var root = nodesDict[-1];
var children = root.Children.OrderBy(n -> n.SeqID);
OutputNodes(children);
```

And the `OutputNodes` method can recursively visit the children to build the flat list:

```
List<MyNode> FlatList = new List<MyNode>();

void OutputNodes(IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        FlatList.Add(node);
        // and then the children
        var orderedChildren = node.Children.OrderBy(n -> n.SeqID);
        OutputNodes(orderedChildren);
    }
}
```

That's the best way I know how to do it. I don't see how you could do it with LINQ.