# Algorithm to sort work orders based on Id and Dependency

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of orders:

```
id, dependency_id
1,  2
1,  3
3,  4
5,  2
3,  6
```

I have to output something like this:

```
Id: 1, Name: Order 1
Dependencies
   Id: 2, Name: Order 2
   Id: 3, Name: Order 3
   Dependencies
      Id: 4, Name: Order 4
      Id: 6, Name: Order 6
Id: 5, Name: Order 5
Dependencies
   Id: 2, Name: Order 2
```

What sort of recursive algorithm should I use? I am stuck

This is what I have so far:

```py
dependencies = {}
def read():
  f = open("dependencies.txt", "r")
  # contents = f.read() #reads the whole file
  #print(contents) #prints everything
  #print(contents[0]) #prints first letter
  lines = f.readlines()
  for i in range(1, len(lines)):
    dep = lines[i].split(",")
    dep[1] = dep[1].rstrip()
    try:
      depList = dependencies.get(dep[0], [])
      depList.append(dep[1])
      dependencies[dep[0]] = depList
    except:
      dependencies[dep[0]] = [dep[1]]
if __name__ == "__main__":
  read()
```

This returns: {'1': ['2', '3'], '3': ['4', '6'], '5': ['2']}

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27277605/56778 shows how to do this in C#. You could use the same technique in Python.

Comment: Is the order supposed to represent the traversal order or is it just a copy of the value?

Comment: You need to have an adjacency list created first for each node and also calculate the in-degree of each node. Then just implement DFS where you only print the nodes after you are done with complete DFS. Store them in Stack till then and after DFS is over, print the stack elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this;

```py
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

table = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 2), (3, 6)]

deps = {}
for k, d in table:
    if k not in deps:
        deps[k] = {}
    if d not in deps:
        deps[d] = {}

    deps[k][d] = True
    deps[d][k] = True

def p(a, d, stack):
    print "%sId: %d, Name: Order %d" % (d * "  ", a, a)
    stack.append(a)
    for b, v in deps[a].iteritems():
        if not b in stack:
            print (d*"  ") + " Dependencies"
            p(b, d+1, stack)

for k, d in table:
    p(k, 0, [])
```

Comment: this almost gets the job done. you do not need deps[d][k] = True 
but prints duplicates for each item in the table list. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I am working on this problem and I have hit a wall. I think I approached it the wrong way. I had originally converted orders.txt and dependencies.txt to DataFrames. And was hoping there would be a way to enforce dependencies this way, but this is incorrect. - I am confused as to how I can apply the dependencies outlined in the dependencies.txt file to the orders.txt file.